# How to setup a website using XAMPP on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server

I wanted to setup a **local** website using XAMPP. I did as their website said. I added the following to my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

[image: virtual hosts screenshot]

and the following to my `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file:

[image: hosts file screenshot]

But yet on going to `mypage.localhost` I get the following error:

[image: screenshot]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post text as text, not images.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation @Scott but when i tried to post it as text, the <VirtualHost*:80> and </VirtualHost> tags did not show up on the preview.

Comment: Paste it, select it, and type Ctrl+K — that will indent every line by four spaces, which will cause it to display correctly (see Anaksunaman's answer). Or just manually type four spaces before every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to ensure that Apache has permission to access the directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mypage.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\SparklyZebra2019\Documents\css projects\CSS Main"

    # Controls general access permissions
    <Directory "C:\Users\SparklyZebra2019\Documents\css projects\CSS Main">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is necessary because you are attempting to access a directory outside the `DocumentRoot` set in `httpd.conf` (i.e. which already has certain permissions configured).

You can add additional directives as required. Using (roughly) the same global configuration options for the `DocumentRoot` specified in `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mypage.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\SparklyZebra2019\Documents\css projects\CSS Main"

    # Controls general access permissions and other options
    <Directory "C:\Users\SparklyZebra2019\Documents\css projects\CSS Main">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

- `Indexes` allows the directory contents to be shown if there is no e.g. `index.html` file.
- `FollowSymLinks` tells Apache to follow symbolic links.
- `AllowOverride` controls what directives may be placed in `.htaccess` files.

You can find more on the `Options` directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) and `AllowOverride` directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).